# Hadoop: TaskTracker shuts down immediately after start-all.sh

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running Hadoop 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

> ./bin/start-all.sh

command does not prompt any errors but the TaskTracker fails to start with the following error in the tasktracker.log file:

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$LocalStorage.checkDirs(TaskTracker.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1447)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3716)
```

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6280989

Comment: That guy seems to have a problem with permissions. I already changed the ownership of the files and permissions are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try first starting dfs by `start-dfs.sh` then MapReduce by `start-mapred.sh` Let's see which process actually causes the error.