# Cannot get tasktracker started on cygwin due to permission failure

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I have setup hadoop 1.1.1 on cygwin under windows 7. The dfs components are starting fine (start-dfs.sh or start-all.sh both) so is jobtracker (start mapred.sh) but the tasktracker fails to start and shuts down with error related to permissions on path to taskTracker (fails to set 0755). I have seen a similar issue reported at [Problem starting tasktracker in hadoop under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276642/problem-starting-tasktracker-in-hadoop-under-windows) but did not find any solution or guidance on how to solve it. Have tried number of websites for solutions too but all in vain.

Here's the log output

```
     2013-01-02 15:51:31,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as 120173
     2013-01-02 15:51:31,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /tmp/hadoop-120173/mapred/local
     2013-01-02 15:51:31,852 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-120173\mapred\local\taskTracker to 0755
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:810)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1557)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3893)

    2013-01-02 15:51:31,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

I have even tried to manually set permission on this directory and then run tasktracker but it still fails.

Comment: Dinkar,Did u find any solution for this problem,i am also facing the same ?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to hadoop-7682 bug and you have to apply a jar patch in order to resolve this issue.
You can find the patch and instructions here

https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the default directory in `hdfs-site.xml` so that the directory that hadoop creates for the `dfs` is a subdir of the cygwin directory. Change the `hdfs-site.xml` like this:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>c:/cygwin/usr/somedir/dfs/name</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>c:/cygwin/usr/somedir/dfs/data</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Amar thanks. The folder where taskTracker is failing is under cygwin only.. it's D:/cygwin/tmp/hadoop-120173/mapred/local/taskTracker.. but this error doesn't seem to be about dfs name and data folders. I will try putting these entires explicitly in hdfs-site and try.. will post here.

Comment: @Dinkar Gupta did this solution work for you ? I'm experiencing same issue